# How can i check programmatically if a user is browse a specific page based in the url slug in Grav CMS using twig syntax?

Tags: twig, grav

I build a custom theme in Grav CMS and i want to exclude a slider block when a user browse the categories page. Here is my code in twig template file:

```
{% if page.route() != '/category' %} 
{% block slider %}
{% include 'partials/slider.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
{% endif  %}
```

However the slider block is always there, no matter if category page or any other page is browsed!
In debug bar there aren't any errors! What i 'm missing here ?

Comment: You can't dynamically include/exclude blocks. Move your `if` inside the block

Comment: I already did that and didn't work either

Comment: did you print out `page.route()`?

Comment: yep i did. I also tried with page.url 
My page url is localhost/games/en/category:Action and with {{ page.url }} i get: /games/en/  missing all other parameters!

Comment: Your checking for exact match here. Go with `{% if not '/category' in page.route() %}`

Comment: it wont work because `{{ page.route }}` output only the `/games/en` missing `/category:Action`

Comment: Checkout the [uri](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/theme-vars#uri-object) variable. Perhaps you can get the info you want from that

Comment: Ok thank you i will check it.

Comment: @Designer, Is your 'categories page' a `blog.md` page?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments in the OP, the `uri` object is the way to determine if a [`param`](https://learn.getgrav.org/16/themes/theme-vars#param-id) is on the url.

```
{% block slider %}
{%   if uri.param('category') %} 
{%     include 'partials/slider.html.twig' %}
{%   endif  %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the `if` statement should be inside the block.